# Three.js Panorama Video texture on mobile

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video

I'm using this example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_video_panorama_equirectangular

For a panoramic video player using Three.js which is fine on desktop, but doesn't render on mobile. Just get a black screen and the following warnings:

```
three.min.js:573 THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float extension not supported.
three.min.js:573 THREE.WebGLRenderer: OES_texture_float_linear extension not supported.
three.min.js:573 THREE.WebGLRenderer: EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic extension not supported.
```

Is there any way to this working on mobile - or am I doomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of mobile browsers disabled autoplay by default, it requires user interaction (e.g. a click event) to start the video. I believe it's a good intention to save initiate data bandwidth.

> ### [Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html)
>
> Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s >expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS—the user >always initiates playback. A controller is automatically supplied on iPhone or >iPod touch once playback in initiated, but for iPad you must either set the >controls attribute or provide a controller using JavaScript.

You just need to create a playback button like below, which is working on my Nexus 7.

```
playbackButton.onclick = function(){
    video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
}
```

For iOS, it's a bit tricky. First issue you would have to deal with is the video format support. The example is using webm which is currently not supported. See [Can I Use WebM](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm) for more support detail .

Good news is that switch to mp4 format this will work half-way. iOS Safari has its own native fullscreen video player which will take over the screen with video content instead of three.js rendering, so basically you would need inline video player solution (e.g. www.brid.tv/in-page-mobile-monetization/) or js-based currentTime trick (e.g. pchen66.github.io/Panolens/examples/panorama_video.html).

Hope this answers your question. :)